# ImageView`s method setCenter not word in storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I want to Initialize ImageView`s location in viewDidLoad method so i wrote below

```
//ViewController.h
//logoImage linked in storyboard
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage;

//ViewController.m
@synthesize logoImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [logoImage setCenter: CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y*0.7)];
    [logoImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

color changed well, but location doesn`t changed.
I want to know why and how to fix it

thank you for reading my ugly english.
hope you understand my question...

Comment: It doesn't move at all? It's unlikely that you want to use `self.view.center`. Try with `CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width.x * 0.5, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.7)`

Comment: does not move at all. both of it! Driving me crazy...

Comment: Why aren't you setting the position in the storyboard with auto-layout?